# How to handle scenarios for python lists containing filenames for comparison?

Tags: python-3.x, list, file

```
l1 =["a_file1.txt","b_file2.txt","c_file3.txt","d_file4.txt"]
l2 =["e_file1.txt","f_file2.txt","g_file3.txt","h_file4.txt"]
```

Two lists containing filenames. I want to compare each file of both list.
Example: File name ending with `"*_file1.txt"` exists in both list. So, it should consider both for comparison.

If both lists are different as shown below. It shouldn't consider `"*_file2.txt"` for comparison and it should print that file doesn't exist.

```
l1 =["a_file1.txt","c_file3.txt","d_file4.txt"]
l2 =["e_file1.txt","f_file2.txt","g_file3.txt","h_file4.txt"]
```

Similarly, `"*_file3.txt"`

```
l1 =["a_file1.txt","b_file2.txt","c_file3.txt","d_file4.txt"]
l2 =["e_file1.txt","f_file2.txt","h_file4.txt"]
```

Another case,

```
l1 =["a_file1.txt","b_file2.txt","c_file3.txt","d_file4.txt"]
l2 =[]
```

How do I handle these scenarios ?

**Tried:**

```
for i in l1:
   ext = i.split("_")
   ext = ext[-1]
   for j in l2:
      if j.endswith(ext):
           print("File found, comparing")
           break
      else:
           print("File not found")
```

Any better approach than this ? Any optimization ?

How can it be handled for file names like below.
Number of files can be more with `some_random_name` (text) `.txt`

```
l1 =["a_file_random_text_ace.txt","b_file_random_text_bdf.txt","c_file_random_text_gik.txt","d_file_random_text_lmn.txt"]
l2 =["e_file_random_text_ace.txt","f_file_random_text_bdf.txt","g_file_random_text_gik.txt","h_file_random_text_lmn.txt"]
```

Comment: you should try to substitute endswith with the in operator.I don't know if this will optimize your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge `l1` and `l2` be the number found in filename and the group them by this number. If we "tag" the lists (for example with number `1` for `l1` and number `2` for `l2`) then we can use `itertools.product` to produce filename pairs.

For example:

```
l1 =["a_file1.txt","b_file2.txt","c_file3.txt","d_file4.txt"]
l2 =["e_file1.txt","f_file2.txt","g_file3.txt","h_file4.txt"]

import re
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby, product

r = re.compile(r'_file(\d+)\.txt$')

# if l1, l2 are sorted by the number, skip sorted:
l1 = sorted(l1, key=lambda k: int(r.search(k).group(1)))
l2 = sorted(l2, key=lambda k: int(r.search(k).group(1)))

l1 = ((v, 1) for v in l1)
l2 = ((v, 2) for v in l2)

m = merge(l1, l2, key=lambda k: int(r.search(k[0]).group(1)))

for _, g in groupby(m, lambda k: int(r.search(k[0]).group(1))):
    g = [*g]
    files_from_l1 = [file for file, n in g if n == 1]
    files_from_l2 = [file for file, n in g if n == 2]
    for f1, f2 in product(files_from_l1, files_from_l2):
        print('Comparing {} to {}'.format(f1, f2))
```

Prints:

```
Comparing a_file1.txt to e_file1.txt
Comparing b_file2.txt to f_file2.txt
Comparing c_file3.txt to g_file3.txt
Comparing d_file4.txt to h_file4.txt
```

For input:

```
l1 =["a_file1.txt","b_file2.txt","c_file3.txt","d_file4.txt"]
l2 =["e_file1.txt","f_file2.txt","h_file4.txt"]
```

Prints:

```
Comparing a_file1.txt to e_file1.txt
Comparing b_file2.txt to f_file2.txt
Comparing d_file4.txt to h_file4.txt
```

---

For input:

```
l1 =["a_file1.txt","b_file2.txt","c_file3.txt","d_file4.txt"]
l2 =[]
```

Prints none.

---

EDIT (To compare by different key):

```
l1 =["a_file_random_text_ace.txt","b_file_random_text_bdf.txt","c_file_random_text_gik.txt","d_file_random_text_lmn.txt"]
l2 =["e_file_random_text_ace.txt","f_file_random_text_bdf.txt","g_file_random_text_gik.txt","h_file_random_text_lmn.txt"]

import re
from heapq import merge
from itertools import groupby, product

r = re.compile(r'_(.*?)\.txt$')

# if l1, l2 are sorted, skip this:
l1 = sorted(l1, key=lambda k: r.search(k).group(1))
l2 = sorted(l2, key=lambda k: r.search(k).group(1))

l1 = ((v, 1) for v in l1)
l2 = ((v, 2) for v in l2)

m = merge(l1, l2, key=lambda k: r.search(k[0]).group(1))

for _, g in groupby(m, lambda k: r.search(k[0]).group(1)):
    g = [*g]
    files_from_l1 = [file for file, n in g if n == 1]
    files_from_l2 = [file for file, n in g if n == 2]
    for f1, f2 in product(files_from_l1, files_from_l2):
        print('Comparing {} to {}'.format(f1, f2))
```

Prints:

```
Comparing a_file_random_text_ace.txt to e_file_random_text_ace.txt
Comparing b_file_random_text_bdf.txt to f_file_random_text_bdf.txt
Comparing c_file_random_text_gik.txt to g_file_random_text_gik.txt
Comparing d_file_random_text_lmn.txt to h_file_random_text_lmn.txt
```

Comment: Kesley : Thank you. It works. How can we handle if there's some text like 'some_random_text.txt','someother_random_text.txt' instead of number (1,2,3,4) ?

Comment: @StackGuru Can you edit your question and put there sample `l1` and `l2` and how they should compare in this case?

Comment: Thank you. change in regex did that.